# I can't seem to get the msvc linker to work properly on vscode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, compilation

I have this really simple program that's made up of 2 files.
main.cpp has the main function:

```
[main.cpp]
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "calculator.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Calculator calc;
    do {
        string op, left, right;
        float out;

        cout << endl << "insert an operator and two numbers: ";
        cin >> op;
        if (calc.isOperator(op)) {
            cin >> left;
            cin >> right;
            out = calc.doOp(op, left, right);
            cout << endl << "result: " << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << endl << "invalid operator" << endl;

    } while(true);
}
```

calculator.cpp has the Calculator class and calculator.h has a declaration for the class and every function or variable in it.

```
[calculator.cpp]
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Calculator {
    vector<float>* mem_stack;

public:
    Calculator() {
        mem_stack = new vector<float>();
    }

    ~Calculator() {
        delete mem_stack;
    }

    float memPeek() {
        return (*mem_stack).back();
    }

    float memPeek(const int& age) {
        return (*mem_stack)[(*mem_stack).size() - age];
    }

    float doOp(const string& op, string& left, string& right) {
        float a, b;

        if (left[0] == 'r') {
            left = left.substr(1, left.size() - 1);
            a = memPeek(stoi(left));
        }
        else
            a = stoi(left);

        if (right[0] == 'r') {
            right = right.substr(1, right.size() - 1);
            b = memPeek(stoi(right));
        }
        else
            b = stoi(right);

        float out;
        if (op == "+")
            out = a + b;
        else if (op == "-")
            out = a - b;
        else if (op == "*")
            out = a * b;
        else if (op == "/")
            out = a / b;
        (*mem_stack).push_back(out);

        return memPeek();
    }

    bool isOperator(const string& op) {
        bool out;
        out = op == "+" && op == "-" && op == "*" && op == "/";
        return out;
    }
};
```

```
[calculator.h]
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Calculator {
private:
    std::vector<float>* mem_stack;
public:
    Calculator();
    ~Calculator();
    float memPeek();
    float memPeek(const int& age);
    float doOp(const std::string& op, std::string& left, std::string& right);
    bool isOperator(const std::string& op);
};
```

When I try to compile the program I get unresolved linking errors in the main function. They all look like this:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
```

I get them for every function from calculator.cpp called in main, including the constructor and destructor
I have looked up everything I could find on this but I still get those errors. Could anybody help me?
I'm still just a rookie.

Comment: My guess is you've overloaded your Calculator constructor without writing a default constructor. Can we see Calculator.h and Calculator.cpp?

Comment: Also the specific error would be very helpful. It should tell you which function failed to link. Please remember to post details like that!

Comment: Configuring Visual Studio Code to use the Visual Studio build tools seems kind of odd. Why not use Visual Studio?

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question and added calculator.cpp and .h.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You may have solved this in the meantime, but your problem is pretty simple: in your `Calculator.cpp` file, you're basically **redeclaring** another Calculator class, which shadows the original one, that ends up with no functions defined for it (just the declarations in the `.h` file). To solve this, you instead declare your member functions with `ClassName::functionName()` in the `.cpp` instead.

Didn't try compiling, but this should work:

```
[calculator.cpp]
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


Calculator::Calculator() {
    mem_stack = new vector<float>();
}

Calculator::~Calculator() {
    delete mem_stack;
}

float Calculator::memPeek() {
    return (*mem_stack).back();
}

float Calculator::memPeek(const int& age) {
    return (*mem_stack)[(*mem_stack).size() - age];
}

float Calculator::doOp(const string& op, string& left, string& right) {
    float a, b;

    if (left[0] == 'r') {
        left = left.substr(1, left.size() - 1);
        a = memPeek(stoi(left));
    }
    else
        a = stoi(left);

    if (right[0] == 'r') {
        right = right.substr(1, right.size() - 1);
        b = memPeek(stoi(right));
    }
    else
        b = stoi(right);

    float out;
    if (op == "+")
        out = a + b;
    else if (op == "-")
        out = a - b;
    else if (op == "*")
        out = a * b;
    else if (op == "/")
        out = a / b;
    (*mem_stack).push_back(out);

    return memPeek();
}

bool Calculator::isOperator(const string& op) {
    bool out;
    out = op == "+" && op == "-" && op == "*" && op == "/";
    return out;
}
```

As a side note, I don't know of your programming background, but one thing struck me out as very odd in your code. Maybe you've come from Java or C#, where you always have to initialize object member variables; C++ is a bit more like C in this respect, in that it allows you to hold objects by value, and not only reference. Which means you don't have to have a pointer to your `vector<float>`, nor allocate/deallocate it yourself; let the compiler do the work for you and use it by value.

So, instead of doing `std::vector<float>* mem_stack;`, simply do `std::vector<float> mem_stack;`; this makes operations like `(*mem_stack).push_back(out);` (or the alternative `mem_stack->push_back(out);`, using the `->` deference operator) much cleaner: `mem_stack.push_back(out);`